Implementation of U3 and U1 gate in Qiskit-1.0
How do I implement those two gates in the new version of Qiskit? I have used RY and PhaseShift resp. but I don't know if it's correct or not.

Although deprecated, U1Gate and U3Gate are still part of Qiskit 1.x, and you can still use them using append method as follows:
from qiskit.circuit.library import U1Gate, U3Gate

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.append(U1Gate(np.pi / 4), [0])
circ.append(U3Gate(np.pi, np.pi / 2, np.pi / 4), [0])

However, it is recommended to use QuantumCircuit.p() instead of u1 and QuantumCircuit.u() instead of u3. They are direct replacements.
circ.p(np.pi / 4, 0)
circ.u(np.pi, np.pi / 2, np.pi / 4, 0)

